# Группа подлежащего ("сорок лунных зайцев")

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите пожалуйста, в предложении "сорок лунных зайцев побежали по дорожке" входит ли "лунных" в подлежащее??

Answer (score 1):

> ...в предложении "сорок лунных зайцев побежали по дорожке" входит ли
>   "лунных" в подлежащее?

Нет, ***лунных*** здесь -- определение. Подлежащее -- ***сорок зайцев***.

Comment: огромное спасибо, я так объяснила ребенку, но не могу объяснить почему! как вы думаете?

Comment: Почему? Ну хотя бы потому, что и без этого слова предложение может существовать. Основа -- _**сорок зайцев (подл.) побежали (сказ.)**_. Остальные слова в этом предложении -- второстепенные, дополняющие подлежащее и сказуемое.

Comment: еще раз большое спасибо! вы очень понятно объяснили. спасибо за ваше время

Answer (score 0):

Сорок зайцев - подлежащее.

**Пояснение**

Количественное числительное в сочетании с именем существительным (количественно-именное сочетание, счетный  оборот) является **единым  членом  предложения.**

Comment: спасибо, я поняла